# Webpage that you can open max in 3 tabs - how?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to make webpage this way? And how?
I can use events like onunload or onbeforeunload in javascript, but not every browser handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot change the number of tabs a user can open from a remote server.

Comment: really? Even display in 4 tab other page than main?

Comment: Client side javascript controls the browser. . .

Comment: Using javascript, you can attempt* to open additional windows, but you cannot limit the number of window/tabs a user has open.

*The user must have javascript enabled.

Comment: I can collect IP's to database, and then check if there are 3 connections. But not every browser handle onunload, onbeforeunload events so I cant odd 1 connection from IP.

Answer (score 2):

People probably won't like this, but an option is to use `localStorage` to store how many windows are open. In your page's `<head>` section:

```
// Check localStorage item - if it exists, see if the count is 3 (or greater, I guess)
//   -If so, redirect this page somewhere else (attempt to use window.close(), otherwise redirect this page to some other page)
//   -If not, increment the counter
// If localStorage item doesn't exist - create it and set it to 1
// What I mean by "item" is that localStorage is basically key/value pairs, so check for your key you want to store this as    

$(window).on("unload", function () {
    // Decrement count in localStorage
});
```

I'm not sure how "unload" works when the browser process is terminated in an unexpected way, but that could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You cannot prevent a website from opening a new tab page that way.
Or the user should allow you to get access to his pc in order to keep count of the tabs.. (But who on earth would accept that?)

Comment: it isn't just about only javascript. As I said above in comment. I can collect IP's to database, but wonder how to remove it from db for every browser.

Comment: You can unload after a certain time, but what if 4 users at same ip open a website? Won't work!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little crude but might work. If you can recognize a user (login etc) then you can have a JS based heartbeat msg going from the browser to your server say every 1-2 secs with the username and a unique identifier for each open page. So that way you know on the server, based on how many unique heartbeats are coming for a user, that in how many tabs the page is open for a user and if he tries 4th you can decline to serve the page from the server. You can consider a tab closed once the heartbeat msgs stop for sat 30 sec or 1 min (timeout).

This can handle the unexpected browser close and does not require any special access to client side environment.